# Android - Physical Back Button on TextEdit erases content

Tags: android, listview, button, android-edittext, back

I have a `ListActivity` with an `EditText` and a `ListView`. Content of the `ListView` changes according to the `EditText` content. I do the following steps:

1) Fill in something in the `EditText`

2) Consequently the `Listview` changes (properly)

3) I scroll the listview

4) I press the back button

At this point I expect to get back to the previous activity, while i happens that the `EditText` gets erased and consequently the `ListView` empty.

Is there a way to tell the `EditText` not to erase itself when Back Button is pressed?

Thanks a lot.

G

Comment: when I press back button keyboard hides and when I press it again it goes to the previous activity in stack. are you shure this is an standart EditText? are you shure u press back button - not erase button? are you shure u didn't override onBackPressedMethod in your activity?

Comment: Yes, it is a standard EditText. Is there a physical erase button on an Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want the activity to finish whenever i press back button. Doesn't matter what i was doing and which object had the focus

Here's how you can force a finish of the `Activity` when back is pressed...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save the editText in the Shared Preferences. To always have the text saved when you back or when you open again the application.Take a look : [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Like this:

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
```

In your SecondClass:

```
pref.edit().putString("text", Text).commit();
```

MainClass:

```
String texto = pref.getString("text", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onPause method to store the EditText value. Either in [SharedPrefrence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or a [Global variable](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/defining-global-variables-in-android/).

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Get the current value from Edit text and store the value on sharedpref or global variable
}
```

here inside onPause method you can save the current value of the EditText into shared preference.

alternatively you can overide the back button's event and do the same as below
you can use following method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
 //your code here to save it to shared pref or global varialble then invoke relevant activity manually
}
```

to overide the events when the back button is pressed

Comment: when you press back button activity is popped from back stack and destroyed.

Comment: then you can call `finish()` inside above method to finish the current activity.

Comment: can u exaplain how overriding the above you can save text in editext?

Comment: I updated the answer. @Raghunandan Thanks for pointing out that I had a half baked answer. Apreciated.

Comment: global vairables meaning static?

Comment: The proble is that the focus remains on the EditText and pressing Back erase the content instead of directly finishing the activity. How can i work this out?

Comment: I just want the activity to finish whenever i press back button. Doesn't matter what i was doing and which object had the focus..

Comment: Perhaps I haven't been clear, it's not a matter of persistance.

Comment: If I override the OnBackPressed() method in my activity like this: @Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
  this.finish();
 }
Will the activiti finish in any case? Even if the focus was on the EditText?